# WADL generation for rest WITHOUT using maven

Tags: java, rest, wadl

I am new bie to Java REST service. I need to generate WADL file automatically once the application is built for my documentation purpose. There are many examples, but all are related to maven. In my java application **I am not using maven**. I need steps in order to generate WADL file automatically once the application is built **without using maven**. I am using jackson-jaxrs-1.5.7.jar

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Depends what the implementation of REST you are using. In case of jersey [JAX-RS] 2.5.1 onward it is auto generate - check the link - https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/wadl.html

Comment: hi  @Naveen Ramawat - I am using jaxrs-1.5.7. I need step by step procedure to build automatically